# What is layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier used in CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

What is `layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier` used in `CollapsingToolbarLayout` ?

I have seen the [android developer doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/R.attr.html#layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier), but I didn't understand.

please explain this parameter & it's effect when it used with `layout_collapseMode` with example.

Below is a simple example of xml.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout ... >
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:src="@drawable/random_pattern"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.75"/>
 </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In very simple words:

When scrolling we see the following - appbar image starts hiding under the content and beyond the top edge of the screen.
Parameter `layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier` determines what part of the image (in percent) will be hidden under the bottom content.

So, for example, setting this parameter to value `1.0` means that top boundary of appbar's image is bound to the top edge of the screen and doesn't move when scrolling. And main content is moving up the top of the image.

When the parameter is not set this corresponds to the value `0.5` and image will be overlapped above and below synchronously.

Comment: exactly the answer I was looking for

Comment: how can i change the sliding up animation to sliding down animation in app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" ?

Answer (score 4):

This was explained on [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.id/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html):

> In addition to pinning a view, you can use `app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"` (and optionally `app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"` **to set the parallax multiplier**) to implement parallax scrolling (say of a sibling `ImageView` within the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`). This use case pairs nicely with the `app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"` attribute for `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, adding a full bleed scrim when the view is collapsed.

This is [a behavior example](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQscXNQY3dNdVlYeTQ/patterns-scrolling-techniques_flex_space_image_xhdpi_003.webm) when you use `app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"`.

Comment: hi Anggrayudi how it  set the image, how a background of tooolbar ?